# DolphinDB: Data deduplication

Tags: duplicates, dolphindb

How to do data deduplication in DolphinDB, is there any example I can refer to? Now, it seems that the database keeps all the data. I can see keyedTable or indexedTable will discard the duplication data, but is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

- Deduplicate when writing data (in version 2.0 or later):

  To find your installed version and see if you need to update, run `version`. Update to the newest version at [www.dolphindb.com](http://www.dolphindb.com).

  TSDB engine is needed to conduct data deduplication. Specify the parameter 'engine' in function 'database' to be "TSDB" to enable the TSDB engine:

```sql
  login(`admin,`123456)
  if(existsDatabase("dfs://tsdb"))
  {
      dropDatabase("dfs://tsdb")
  }
  //create a distributed database and specify the parameter engine to be TSDB
  db_tsdb = database(directory = "dfs://tsdb", partitionType = VALUE, partitionScheme = 2012.03.01..2022.12.31, engine = 'TSDB')
```

Then create 3 DFS tables with different deduplication rules. Specify the sort columns by parameter sortColumns and the data deduplication rules by the parameter keepDuplicates in createPartitionedTable. The data deduplication runs only when duplicated key values are identified. There are 3 optional deduplication rules:

- Last: Keep the latest data.
- ALL: Keep all data.
- FIRST: Keep the first data.

In the following case, we create 3 DFS tables, specify key columns to be "ID" and "Date" and `keepDuplicates` to be "LAST", "ALL" and "FIRST" respectively:

```sql
t = table(1:0,`Date`ID`Close,[DATETIME,SYMBOL,DOUBLE])

tsdb_table = createPartitionedTable(dbHandle = db_tsdb, table=t, tableName="last",  sortColumns=["ID","Date"],  partitionColumns=`Date, keepDuplicates=LAST)
last = db_tsdb.loadTable(`last)

tsdb_table = createPartitionedTable(dbHandle = db_tsdb, table=t, tableName="all",  sortColumns=["ID","Date"],  partitionColumns=`Date, keepDuplicates=ALL)
all = db_tsdb.loadTable(`all)

tsdb_table = createPartitionedTable(dbHandle = db_tsdb, table=t, tableName="first",  sortColumns=["ID","Date"],  partitionColumns=`Date, keepDuplicates=FIRST)
first = db_tsdb.loadTable(`first)
```

Write data with no duplicated sort columns and query the table:

```sql
Date = 2012.03.01 09:30:00..(2012.03.01 09:30:00 + 4)
ID = `000001`000001`000002`000002`000002
Close =1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 
first_table = table(Date,ID,Close)

last.append!(first_table)
all.append!(first_table)
first.append!(first_table)

select * from last
select * from all
select * from first
```

The above 3 tables return the same results as shown in the chart.

[image: attachments-2021-11-B5kR5Vve61920a66dd000.png]

Then write data with the same sort columns.

```
Date = 2012.03.01 09:30:00..(2012.03.01 09:30:00 + 4)
ID = `000001`000001`000002`000002`000002
Close =10.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 50.0 
second_table = table(Date,ID,Close)

last.append!(second_table)
all.append!(second_table)
first.append!(second_table)

select * from last
select * from all
select * from first
```

With different data written, the query results will be different as the 3 tables apply different deduplication rules.

Table with the `LAST` parameter keeps the latest data where keyColumns are duplicated:

[image: attachments-2021-11-MNwMstWy61920c04e31e5.png]

Table with the `FIRST` parameter keeps the first data where keyColumns are duplicated:

[image: attachments-2021-11-sBXxXIEO61920d696962e.png]

Table with the `ALL` parameter keeps the data written for each time where keyColumns are duplicated:

[image: attachments-2021-11-J5NYzI9i61920c75e728c.png]

**My Script:**

```sql
login(`admin,`123456)
if(existsDatabase("dfs://tsdb"))
{
    dropDatabase("dfs://tsdb")
}

db_tsdb = database(directory = "dfs://tsdb", partitionType = VALUE, partitionScheme = 2012.03.01..2022.12.31, engine = 'TSDB')

t = table(1:0,`Date`ID`Close,[DATETIME,SYMBOL,DOUBLE])

tsdb_table = createPartitionedTable(dbHandle = db_tsdb, table=t, tableName="last",  sortColumns=["ID","Date"],  partitionColumns=`Date, keepDuplicates=LAST)
last = db_tsdb.loadTable(`last)

tsdb_table = createPartitionedTable(dbHandle = db_tsdb, table=t, tableName="all",  sortColumns=["ID","Date"],  partitionColumns=`Date, keepDuplicates=ALL)
all = db_tsdb.loadTable(`all)

tsdb_table = createPartitionedTable(dbHandle = db_tsdb, table=t, tableName="first",  sortColumns=["ID","Date"],  partitionColumns=`Date, keepDuplicates=FIRST)
first = db_tsdb.loadTable(`first)

Date = 2012.03.01 09:30:00..(2012.03.01 09:30:00 + 4)
ID = `000001`000001`000002`000002`000002
Close =1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 
first_table = table(Date,ID,Close)

last.append!(first_table)
all.append!(first_table)
first.append!(first_table)

select * from last
select * from all
select * from first

Date = 2012.03.01 09:30:00..(2012.03.01 09:30:00 + 4)
ID = `000001`000001`000002`000002`000002
Close =10.0 20.0 30.0 40.0 50.0 
second_table = table(Date,ID,Close)

last.append!(second_table)
all.append!(second_table)
first.append!(second_table)

select * from last
select * from all
select * from first
```